# Ternary operator and assignment

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to save sole lines of code in my VB.NET project using ternary `If` operator, but getting thrown:

> "Specified Cast is no valid"

```
' THIS WORKS FINE
If info.GetString("IdentificationType").Trim = "" Then
    _Expiration = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue
Else
    _Expiration = info.GetValue("Expiration", Expiration.GetType)
End If
```

```
' THIS THROWS AN EXCEPTION
_Expiration = If(info.GetString("IdentificationType").Trim = "",
    System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue,
    info.GetValue("Expiration", Expiration.GetType))
```

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: I'd wager that `GetValue` is actually returning a `DateTime` and not a `SqlDateTime`.  In that case, you should be calling `GetDateTime` rather than `GetValue` and you should be using `DateTime.MinValue` or else converting `SqlDateTime.MinValue` to a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue is of type **System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime**

If I have to guess, Expiration.GetType must be of the type **System.DateTime**.

Add cast **CDate**(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue)

Try this,

```
_Expiration = If(info.GetString("IdentificationType").Trim = "",
    CDate(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue),
    info.GetValue("Expiration", Expiration.GetType))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue
```

and

```
info.GetValue("Expiration", Expiration.GetType)
```

return different types. This is as much answer as I can give without knowing variables and return types.

Bottom line, when you use `If(1, 2, 3)` - 2 and 3 must return same type